# Is it possible to make a stackable label with the Esri LabelLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling

I'd like to add a line break, but the textstring is always taken literally. For example:

`labels.addFeatureLayer(states, statesLabelRenderer, "Line 1 \r\n Line 2");`

is displayed on the map as:

> Line 1 \r\n Line 2

I also tried HTML break tag with no luck either.

Comment: Perhaps try `\\n` (2 backslashes) I don't think you'll need carriage return. Also, I'm not sure if that last parameter is being used correctly. It should be variable substitution: `${CITY_NAME}`

Comment: This prints: ""line1 \n line2".  You can mix variable and text both.

Comment: Oh yes, I get that. I just thought it would be weird that all your labels say the same thing :). This is indeed a curious problem! You might have to end up projecting the line break in the data instead?

Comment: Probably will end up doing that, seems the LabelLayer is a bit limited..

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on what parser you use:
if you are using VB, this is the correct syntax for a new line **& vbnewline &**.
add this between your 2 fields or expressions

[image]

Comment: This is for web, not desktop.

Comment: Lable styles and definitions are published in a bunddle when you publish the map server. It should work fine.

Comment: I was attempting to set the expression dynamically on the client, as it could change.  Moot point now as the LabelLayer has been deprecated.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ASCI URL ENCODED caracters : line feed --> %0A or carriage return --> %0D ?

PS : I wanted to make this a comment but it was not possible since I don't have a reputation of 50 or more!

Comment: Tried both, printed literally as ""line1 %0D line2""

Answer (score 0):

Try the MultiLineTextSymbol plugin on Github:
https://github.com/suytt/esri.symbol.MultiLineTextSymbol